# Link open content in desktop program instead of browser

Tags: html

Is it possible to to create an `<a>` tag that links to a particular resource such as an image or PDF and when the user clicks it, it will open in Windows Preview, Adobe Reader etc (whatever the default program is for that filetype) by using only a URL scheme or something like that?

Comment: Did you tried with something like `<a title="Some PDF" href="my_pdf_location.pdf" target="_blank">Open PDF</a>`?

Comment: `The <a> tag defines a hyperlink, which is used to link from one page to another.` So therefor you can point it on a page that opens the pdf file

Comment: only programs that are intergrated into browser will be used to view files of that type, so pdf is a yes, but Windows Preview is a no, .flv  will use flash etc etc

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible using `<a>` tag to specify opening of an image to be opened up using Windows Preview (not aware of any such plugin). you can integrate picasa though (there is a plugin for major browsers). Same for the adobe pdf plugin.

I guess you want it for your users. and you cannot be sure if all users have the plugins installed, I guess that is why you asked by "...using only a URL scheme or something like that". But I am afraid there is no such facility for `<a>` tag.